# How to start programming in PHP using MVC fresh site

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using an FTP client and started a fresh website. I would like to know how I could make a layout view in PHP. I have seen the concept of using a layout view in ASP.NET, however in ASP.NET the layout view is automatically called when the desired controller calls for the desired view. What causes this process in ASP.NET to happen?

When I check the `<body>` element of the `layout.cshtml` file of a general MVC project, I notice there's this piece of Razor code: `@RenderBody()` and when I look at the `RouteConig.cs` file I notice that this code only calls for the desired controller and view.

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

The `Index.cshtml` file doesn't contain anything that refers to the layout view either. How come the Layout view is always loaded still then? Am I missing something?

I am taking this ASP.NET application as an example so I might be able to understand how I could apply the same strategy in PHP for making the layout view possible.

What would be the equivelant of `@RenderBody()` in PHP aswell? How should I make a layout page look like (if I want it to look similar to a default ASP.NET MVC project)?

Comment: you should look for a tutorial

Comment: The concepts you are asking are too broad for SO. [This resource](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor) is a bit old, but the basic concepts of layouts, etc carry on to this day. Hth